# Filter by multiple conditions / drop-downs using DataTables - Table plug-in for jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery, datatable

Using this example from http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/11/21/datatables-in-visualforce-part-1/ I implemented a Visualforce page that creates a dropdown and filters records in the datatable based on the dropdown value. How would I go about filtering by multiple dropdowns using an "AND" condition. Is that even possible using datatables in jQuery? Everything I've tried so far (Two dropdowns and two-sided multi select lists) have not worked, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
<script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(document).ready( function () {
                var contactTable = j$('[id$="contacttable"]').DataTable({
                    order: [[2, 'asc']],

                    initComplete: function() {
                        var api = this.api();
                        var select = j$('[id$=accountSelect]');
                        api.column(0).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                        } );   
                    }
                });

                j$('[id$=accountSelect]').change(function() {
                    var val = j$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        j$(this).val()
                    );
                    contactTable.column(0)
                        .search( val == 'All' ? '' : '^'+val+'$', true, false )
                        .draw();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes just create two dropdown.

once you int your datatable

just add the script

```
var table = table =  $('#tableId').DataTable( {});

$('#firstDropdownId').on('change', function () {
        table.columns(6).search( this.value).draw();
} );

$('#SecondDropdownId').on('change', function () {
       table.columns(7).search( this.value).draw();
} );
```

**Here 6, 7 are the column no. of your table Using this you can filter the data.**

check out this http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/5Lj6peof/1/

Comment: Great, that helps somewhat. But I want to be able to filter by multiple options on the same column. In the example you're filtering two different columns. Is that possible?

Comment: For multiple options on the same column refer this link https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: @user988 Yahh may be this will help. you can use my yadcf plugin for datatables   http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html

Comment: @user988 jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/ba9mhhq0/

Comment: one simple option you can use regex for filter http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html  jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/p3asur7t/2/

Comment: very useful for cascading dropdown.